# How can I make this function shorter?

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble with this function in PHP. I have a changing amount of posted items on this page, and I'm returning the variable in the array with this function:

```
function grade($a) {
    if ($a == 1) {
        return $_POST['1'];
    }
    if ($a == 2) {
        return $_POST['2'];
    }
    if ($a == 3) {
        return $_POST['3'];
    }
    if ($a == 4) {
        return $_POST['4'];
    }
    if ($a == 5) {
        return $_POST['5'];
    }
    if ($a == 6) {
        return $_POST['6'];
    }
    //... you get the idea
}
```

This is probably not the right way. How can I make this function shorter so that I don't have to make the if-statement for every possible array variable?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Generally you should not name fields as numbers. You should just call the field grade so that you can just get it out of the post `echo $_POST["grade"];`.

Comment: what is this? an attempt at setting the world record for the question with the most amount of answers that say exactly the same?

Comment: @lascort I think most of the people answering are trying to relive the experience of performing trivial and nonsensical tasks that only a classroom environment could dish out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish this very easily by using the value of the variable as the [array](https://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) key:

```
function grade($a) {
    if (!array_key_exists($a, $_POST)) {
        // Given grade key does not exist in the $_POST array
        return null;
    }
    return $_POST[$a];
}
```

You will note that you do not have to convert the integer to a string, as per the [documentation](https://php.net/manual/language.types.array.php):

> Additionally the following key casts will occur:
>
> - Strings containing valid integers will be cast to the integer type. E.g. the key "8" will actually be stored under 8.

Comment: You might have to do "$a" since these are strings

Comment: Woah is it that simple? Can you put a variable in an array like that? Thanks for your help by the way!

Comment: @LoganMurphy PHP will type juggle.

Comment: @user3617942 You dont put the variable. you use the value of the variable as the index of your array.

Comment: +1: This is correct. I would change the `if` statement to `if(array_key_exists(...))`. I think it's better than explicitly returning null (as the function is going to return null if nothing else is returned).

Answer (score 3):

Pretty simple, you just pass the variable on to the return:

```
function grade($a) {
    if( !isset( $_POST[$a] ) )
        return 0;
    return $_POST[$a];
}
```

This also checks if it doesn't exist, to return `0` as your grade.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a switch operator : http://www.php.net/manual/fr/control-structures.switch.php

I'm not using php but this may work as well :

```
function grade($a) {
    return $_POST['' . $a];
}
```

Comment: This is the same as doing `return $_POST[$a]`. How does this answer the question?

Comment: it does answer the question, it concatenates a useless empty string though, but it does answer the question (as all of the other answers in here already)

Comment: I didn't know that $a could be read as a String or a char without that concatenation. Now I do, and that strval($a) does it too. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

make it simple:

```
function grade($a) {
  return isset($_POST[$a]) ? $_POST[$a] : '' ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ternary if would be the shortest.

```
function grade($a)
{
    return isset($_POST[$a])? $_POST[$a] : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can write like bellow

```
function grade($a) { 
    return $_POST[$a];
}
```

Comment: The OP only wants to return a value if `$a` exists inside `$_POST`. Your function does not check for its existence.

Comment: ys. you are right. Af first i should check that value of `$a` is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
function grade($a) {
    if (isset($_POST[$a])) {
        return $_POST[$a];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It is, however, an attempt at a solution that won't work, since the keys in _POST are strings, not ints.

Comment: @david thanks for correction, another option we can use is `array_key_exists`.